# Index for a @NaturalId field in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, entity-relationship

In a Spring Boot app, we use `@NaturalId` for the `isbn` field as shown below:

```
@Entity
public class Book {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @NaturalId
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String isbn;

    @Column(length = 50, nullable = false)
    private String name;
}
```

1. I will use a method e.g. `findByIsbn(String isbn)`. So, do I need to add an index (via annotaion or sql script) for the `isbn` field annotated by `@NaturalId` ?
2. Is it a bad idea to map the `isbn` fields of 2 tables for one-to-many / many-to-one relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the isbn has unique constraint, this constraint will be used as index, so you dont need an extra index.

You can use any unique column in many-to-one relationship and hibernate supports it. You can use @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "isbn") to reference it. And I dont think there are any disadvantages to do it that way.

Comment: **1.** Thanks a lot for your explanations. Yes, there is `ALTER TABLE book ADD CONSTRAINT uc_book_isbn UNIQUE (isbn);` line in the generated migration SQL. In this case, I think I do not need. Then, is it generated due to `@NaturalId` annotation?

Comment: **2.** Another issue is that, for example normally we use numeric field for PK and use this for relation. But the business key fields e.g. "isbn", "email" are String values and for this reason I am not sure if it is good idea to use these fields for relationship. So, should I use this "isbn" field to make relation instead of id so that I can directly use this field? Or should I use "id" field and then retrieve the record and get "email"? What would you suggest?

Comment: **3.** Is the following approach a proper way to use `@NaturalId` in  Spring Boot app? [How to Use Hibernate Natural IDs in Spring Boot](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-use-hibernate-natural-ids-in-spring-boot)

Comment: 1. It is generated due to unique=true in the column annotation

Comment: 2. Yes, i agree about using numeric types. And if you dont have any specific requirement and dependencies in this regard, than prefer use of it as foreign key